# Scala Errors- forward reference extends over definition of value

Tags: scala

I am trying to generate the list of intervals which are not included in a given list starting from 1. So I wrote the code as shown below:

```
def comparatorInt(first: (Int,Int), second: (Int, Int)) = first._2 <= second._1

val list1 = List((93,97), (5,10),(15,20),(30,50), (76,90)).sortWith(comparatorInt)

var curr = 1
val res = for(x <- list1; tmp = curr; curr = x._2+1) yield(tmp,x._1-1)
```

Here I am getting an compiler error

**Error: forward reference extends over definition of value tmp**

**lazy val res = for(x <- list1; tmp = curr; curr = x._2+1) yield(tmp,x._1-1)**

I am not able to figure out the fix for the issue. Kindly suggest a solution for the same.

Comment: You should've accepted the other answer. where the actual answer is ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer explains well enough why you are getting the error. I just wanted to add: do not use `var`, you don't need them most of the time. If you are writing in scala might as well take advantage of the power of the language and stay idiomatic, rather than just writing same old java code with funny syntax :)
Consider something like this:

```
  ((0,0) :: list1).foldRight(List.empty[(Int,Int)]) { 
     case(x@(a, b), res@((c, d) :: tail)) if(b < c-1) => x :: (b+1, c-1) :: res 
     case(x, res)  => x :: res
  }.tail
```

(Besides not causing a compilation error, this version also works correctly, unlike yours, that has logical errors ;)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed. 
I am still new to Scala, so trying to learn as much as possible... will try to continue with your advice. :)

Comment: It will be really helpful, if you could suggest some Links to refer for learning scala's advanced feature as otherwise I come to know about such methods only when trying to solve some problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `curr` in the `for` comprehension is not the same one as your `var`. What you wrote is equivalent to

```
var curr = 1
val res = for(x <- list1; tmp = anotherCurr; anotherCurr = x._2+1) yield(tmp,x._1-1)
```

so the compiler sees that you are trying to define `temp` before you defined `anotherCurr`, hence the error.

If you want to modify the `var`, you can do it after the `yield` operation.

Comment: IntelliJ has a nice code analyzer that will find this sort of thing very easily. I am a long-time Eclipse user but IntelliJ is much better for Scala.